# jQuery: How to let a callback function just run once

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, callback

I want to run a callback function just once, it should run if it removes all elements with a certain class, but for some reason the callback function runs times the number of elements that are removed, so thats not what i am looking for.

The code(form a plugin)

```
     $.plugin= {
        clear: function(str){

            $('.msg').fadeOut(200, function(){
                $(this).remove();
                if(typeof str.remove == 'function'){
                    str.remove.call(this);
                }           
            });
        } 
    }
```

Comment: we need to see more code. no idea what `str` refers to, among other things.

Comment: @maxedison is correct. One of the other things we need to know is the code contained in the `.remove()` method and how it reacts to the scope given to it (since you're specifically `.call()`ing it in scope of the removed element[s]).

Comment: i have updated the code, this is the basic plugin part. I have placed the callback in the scope sinds it should only run if the elements are removed. The call back can contain some kind of fucntion used by a user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to unset the function:

```
    $('.msg').fadeOut(200, function(){
        $(this).remove();
        if(typeof str.remove == 'function'){
            str.remove.call(this);
            str.remove = false;
        }           
    });
```

---

JAAulde might be right.
The following code calls the callback with all .msg elements:

```
    var $msgs = $('.msg').fadeOut(200, function(){
        $(this).remove();
        if(typeof str.remove == 'function'){
            str.remove.call($msgs);
            str.remove = false;
        }           
    });
```

Note that `$('.msg')` is slow (especially in IE 7 and below) and should not be used without a tag.
The reason is that they don't support [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll) (as Mike G said)

Comment: Class selectors in general? Or what is slow?

Comment: Why is it slow? Is it because of the lack of querySelectorAll?

Comment: http://www.artzstudio.com/2009/04/jquery-performance-rules/#use-tags-before-classes

Comment: This may or may not work as intended.  Since the OP is specifically calling `.remove()` in scope of `this` (as it exists inside the fadeOut callback), it now only runs once in scope of the first removed element. Without knowing the code in the `.remove()` callback we don't know if this is problematic.

Comment: Why do you delete the str.remove() method? Maybe it is needed afterwards? If not, it wouldn't be a separate function, will it?

Comment: Yes it's always better to use a element name like div.msg(i have shortend the code for the example)

Answer (score 1):

This should do the task:

```
    var msgs = $('.msg').fadeOut(200);
    msgs.promise().done(function(){
        msgs.remove();
        if(typeof str.remove == 'function'){
            str.remove.call(this);
        }           
    });
```

See http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/#callback-function and http://api.jquery.com/promise/. I'm not sure what `this` refers to in the done callback, so I made the reference sure with an additional variable.

Comment: I dont know the promise api, so i will take a look at it and see what it is.

Comment: It's the thing made to solve your problem :-) OK, no, the [Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) thing is a greater concept, but good to use here.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest an alternative way: since you may need to use that function again later I prefer not overriding the function but calling it just once

```
var l = $('.msg').length;
$('.msg').fadeOut(200, function(){
    $(this).remove();
    if((--l === 0) && typeof str.remove == 'function'){
         str.remove.call(this);
    }           
});
```

if you have to execute both function once just write

```
var l = $('.msg').length;
$('.msg').fadeOut(200, function(){
    if (--l === 0) {
        $(this).remove();
        if(typeof str.remove == 'function'){
           str.remove.call(this);
        } 
    }           
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used the next piece of code(as Ghommey pointed my to the simple false statement).

```
 $.plugin= {
    clear: function(str){

        $('.msg').fadeOut(200, function(){
            $(this).remove();
            if(typeof str.remove == 'function'){
                str.remove.call(this);
                str.remove = false;
            }           
        });
    } 
}
```